# How do I splice a drywall metal outside corner bead?

Tags: drywall, ceiling, corner-bead

When re-finishing my ceiling (formerly popcorn, now smooth) I had some trouble with the edge of the tray ceiling in the master bedroom. Since the length of the tray was longer than a standard metal outside corner bead, the builder spliced several together by overlapping a few inches.

For future reference, is that the correct method for splicing? It was really hard to get a smooth coat of mud over it, since it was a sharp irregularity on the corner. (I never did get it perfect.) If the corner beads were butted instead of overlapped, I don't think I would have run into this problem. Would butting the corner beads cause cracking at their joint? What are some other factors that I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've always butted them together, and I've never had any problems with doing it that way.

Not sure what your builder was thinking by overlapping them.

Comment: OK, that sounds right to me. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't going to run into problems on down the road.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, when butting corner-bead you should, first, cut about a 2" to 3" piece of bead and place it under the butt joint. That way your two pieces will butt together neatly and will be smooth when you mud over them. If your run is longer than 10', you'll need to do this (most bead is 8', but 10' is also available).